# Prove or reject: if $a^2|b^3$ then $a|b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I tried to find a counter example but failed!!
If $a^2|b^3$ then it is obvious that $a|b^3$ because $b^3=ka^2=(ka)a=k'a$ but we hardly can say $a|b$

Comment: Hint: what would happen if $a^2=b^3$?

Comment: @Arthur I think it must have a simpler solution technic

Comment: $a=p^3,\ b=p^2$.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli  That's a general counter example,thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with $a=8$ and $b=12$?

Comment: Excellent: you rejected it by this counter example

Comment: Or $a=8$, $b=4$.